# Selenium-java: Unable to enter the else If block when Xpath is not displayed

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have below piece of code which verifies that If one Xpath is displayed then print some text and if other xpath is displayed then print some text. However, I'm seeing that check is happening for Xpath given in If statement but not skipping and going to Else If. Where I'm doing wrong. Please help!

```
if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='investmentsthird']/section[1]/section[1]/div/h3")).isDisplayed()) {
    System.out.println("submitted");
} else if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='investmentsthird']/div[1]/div/div/h4")).isDisplayed()) {
    System.out.println("failed");
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the second condition is also false. Try to debug it or add `else {  System.out.println("both are wrong");}`

Comment: you mean to say "else if'  condition is getting evaluated though "if block" condition returned "true" and displayed "submitted"?

Comment: Please read [mcve], especially the link at the bottom about how to debug small programs.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the elements are present on the page before the if/else block

```
WebdriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20) 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(by.xpath"//[@id='investmentsthird']/section[1]/section[1]/div/h3")))
if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='investmentsthird']/section[1]/section[1]/div/h3")).isDisplayed()) {
    System.out.println("submitted");
} else if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='investmentsthird']/div[1]/div/div/h4")).isDisplayed()) {
    System.out.println("failed");
}
```